# How to set client timeout in an axis2c client

Tags: timeout, client, axis2c

I had a **WSDL** file then I used `AXIS2C WSDL2C` tool to create the client project.

I modified the `axis2.xml` file.
added this line in the beginning after `<axisconfig name="Axis2/C">`:

```
<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT">8000</parameter>
```

I can now set the timeout. 
How can I handle it in my code?
I mean How can I know that I've got a connection timeout or a socket timeout or the server responded properly.

**Question Update:**
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8ivo6m5xrwcocs/Math.rar?dl=0) is a link to my project :

Answer (score 0):

You should analyze [error code](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/source/browse/util/include/axutil_error.h#348) from `env->error->status_code` after you invoke the client:

```
axiom_node_t* resp = axis2_svc_client_send_receive(client, env, payload);

switch (env->error->status_code)
{
case AXIS2_ERROR_RESPONSE_TIMED_OUT:
  // Timeout
    break;

// other errors goes here ...
}
```

Also if you want to set timeout programmatically:

```
axis2_options_t* opt = axis2_options_create(env)
axis2_options_set_timeout_in_milli_seconds(opt, env, 8000);
axis2_svc_client_set_options(client, env, opt);
```

Comment: Hello. where should I put the first piece of code? should I put it in the main.c ?  should I create all the parameters (svc_client, env, payload) ?
I've edited the question and included a link to my project. It would be very nice of you to tell me what to do.

Comment: As I see you're using ADB. There is no way to get error code when you're using adb unless you modify the generated stub by hand. Search "axis2_svc_client_send_receive_with_op_qname" in your generated 'axis2_stub_MathService.c' and try to add the switch/case there.

Comment: can you clarify a little bit please? I can't seem to find a good solution and I really need to handle the timeouts. @loentar

Comment: 1. open your 'axis2_stub_MathService.c' in any text editor; 2) search for `axis2_svc_client_send_receive_with_op_qname` 3) after found line add swith/case as in my example; 4) implement the code within `case AXIS2_ERROR_RESPONSE_TIMED_OUT:`